# Angular [disabled] does nothing

Tags: html, angular

I use angular 6.2.1

it should disable the submit button but it does nothing ...

this does nothing [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid" but this [disabled]="heroForm.form.valid" it works but it's not what i want

when inputs are empty it should disable the button but it doesn't

it disable the button when [disabled]="heroForm.valid" when the form is valid but it's not what i want. I don't know why it's valid when inputs are empty i use required in every input

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="hola()">
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" 
required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" 
required>
      </div>
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
[disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: if you clean up your question with a little more information we could come up with an answer. (the last section makes no sense and the variable you are using has no context)

Comment: sorry i wrote it but it disappeared

Comment: i think stack overflow is not intuitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try `[disabled] = “heroform.invalid”`

Here is an example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-symxeg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

you are missing the ngModel property and the name property on the input fields and thats why ngForm doesn't know what to validate

Comment: I tried and this disable the button in every case it doesn't consider the expression 
[attr.disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid"  or this  [attr.disabled]="!heroForm.valid" 
it should disable only when inputs are empty

Comment: it just disable in any case without consider the expression

Comment: same result, it doesn't disable the button, but this
[disabled]="heroForm.valid"  it disable but i don't want disable when it is valid

Comment: i think it is a angular issue, this doesn't happen before i update angular cli 6.2.1

Comment: Try invalid instead of valid

Comment: yes i do 
`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>`

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [disabled]="heroForm.invalid">Sign in</button>`

Comment: i tried but it's the same result i post the code it has required in the inputs

Comment: `<form #heroForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [disabled]="heroForm.invalid">Sign in</button>
      </form>`

Comment: I have found the real issue with your code i have edited the answer and included a n example

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
  [disabled]="!heroForm.valid">
  Sign in
</button>
```

Comment: i tried but it's the same, inputs empty but button is not disable

Comment: it disable the button when [disabled]="heroForm.valid" i don't know why it's valid when inputs are empty i use required in every input